# Jenkins-Worker: SSH or JNLP Connection?

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins, jnlp

Right now I found 2 possible solutions creating Jenkins Slaves or Jenkins Workers:

- Using the SSH-Slave Plugin
- Using JNLP

My question now: What is the better / more stable solution and why?

I found myself some pros and cons using both of the solutions but I don't want to affect the discussion

Comment: I have same question, we are using JNLP and its very sensitive to packet drops, any single packet drop breaking connection between slave/master and drop running jobs

Answer (score 3):

- **Java Web Start** -- and the underlying Java Network Launch Protocol (JNLP) is the recommended mode of connection for windows agents.
  [jenkins.wiki.io](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows)
- **SSH** is recommended for Linux agents

The Pros and Cons don't matter if both are recommended for different platforms.

Comment: I'm not sure it's completely platform dependent. Linux running on docker commonly won't have SSH configured and so JNLP is used on Kubernetes. I know SSH blocks on I/O as does JNLPv3. Not sure how JNLPv4 stacks up against SSH and I think that is the answer we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We are only using SSH, mainly because in a corporate setting:

- asking for the JNLP port to be opened on the agent server ([agent being the new name for slave in Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42841))
- any query to another server should use an authenticated flow (like SSH with a key, or an account username/password)

Plus we can add to the Launch method configuration various JVM Options to monitor the GC and other memory parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure this really covers the pros and cons of each.

Comment: @Levi I am less familiar with the pros for JNLP: I don't have the right to use it in a corporate environment.